# call to webmethod using ajax doesn't work

Tags: ajax

I have a webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetVendorData(List<VendorData> LstVendorData)
{
       //something
}
```

and call it from a ajax method

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/WebMethods/AjaxProcessorPage.aspx/GetVendorData",
      ...
      ....
```

This works fine form Content Authoring, but doesn't work on Content delivery.
I included */WebMethods/AjaxProcessorPage.aspx* in the setting name="ignoreUrlprefixes" ... also, but not luck. What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you provide the error?

Comment: Komahan can you hit the endpoint (/WebMethods/AjaxProcessorPage.aspx/GetVendorData) and get a response? or do you get a 404 or other error?

Comment: Could you post the entirety of the ajax call @Komahan? Curious if you have have content type set (ie: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod]
public static string GetVendorData(List<VendorData> LstVendorData)
{
       //something
}
```

or

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/WebMethods/AjaxProcessorPage.aspx/GetVendorData",
      data: JSON.stringify(params),
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try:

1- Use a tool like postman or whatever is your preference to emulate a post to that url. You need to check whether you can reach it or not. Andrei's answer suggest an approach calling directly with an ajax call which helps aslo.
2- In case you can't reach your next try is the routing table to see why you can't reach that method.